# Spatialite Android GEOS module missing

Tags: android, postgresql, spatialite

I'm developing a GIS-based android app where I'm using Spatialite Android jar lib but I'm facing some issues like missing such functions i.e `ST_Line_Substring`,`ST_Line_Locate_Point` which requires GEOS module, the query returning null but in PostgreSQL, the query works perfectly.

```
public Geometry splitHalf(Geometry linestring,Geometry closest_point)  {
    Geometry geo = null;
    String query1 = "SELECT " +
            "ST_AsBinary("+
            "ST_Line_Substring(" +
            "'"+linestring+"',0,ST_Line_Locate_Point('"+linestring+"','"+closest_point+"')));";
    Stmt stmt1 = null;
    Log.v(TAG,query1);
    try {
        stmt1 = db.prepare(query1);
        WKBReader wkbReader = new WKBReader();
        while (stmt1.step()) {
            geo = wkbReader.read(stmt1.column_bytes(0));
        }
        stmt1.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG+":1",e.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return geo;
}
```

Comment: Hej Arpan! Are you sure the database you're querying has the **postgis** extension installed? Which **postgresql** version are you using?

Comment: In my app I'm using Spatialite Android not postgresql. To test my query i used the postgresql.

Comment: Oh I see.. I misunderstood your issue. It's very strange indeed, since spatialite has this functions by default :-( http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.2.0.html .. good luck!

Comment: I don't why it's returning null. What i noticed that functions that requires GEOS are not working.

Comment: I'm not familiar with spatialite, but in previous versions of **postgis** I recall needing to install these functions manually from a .sql file. Maybe worth checking the installation? Cheers and good luck!